# How can I resolve datetime calculation in python with sqllite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime, time

I have a problem for sql updating part in python

Here is the codes working whether check is 1 or 0

```
for k, v in self.db_dictionary.items():        
     if self.db_dictionary[k]['check'] > 0 :
            self.c.execute('''UPDATE table SET Counts = Counts + ?,
                          Latest_Happend_Last_time = ?,
                          Current_Status = ?  
                          WHERE Name = ?''' 
                          ,[self.db_dictionary[k]['check'], 
                            self.current_time,'Alert',k])
            self.conn.commit()

            self.c.execute('''UPDATE table SET 
                          Latest_Happend_Start_time = Latest_Happend_Last_time - "datetime.timedelta(minutes='Plus_Val')",
                          How_Long_time =  Latest_Happend_Last_time - Latest_Happend_Start_time
                          WHERE Name = ?''' 
                          ,[k])
            self.conn.commit()

            self.c.execute('''UPDATE table SET Plus_Val= Plus_Val + 1 
                          WHERE Name = ?''' 
                          ,[k])
            self.conn.commit()

        elif self.db_dictionary[k]['check'] == 0:
            self.c.execute('''UPDATE table SET Current_Status = ?,
                          Plus_Val = ?
                          WHERE Name = ?''' 
                          ,['Normal',0,k])
            self.conn.commit()
```

I want to solve this code area. except below area, other codes can work.

```
                self.c.execute('''UPDATE table SET 
                          Latest_Happend_Start_time = Latest_Happend_Last_time - "datetime.timedelta(minutes='Plus_Val')",
                          How_Long_time =  Latest_Happend_Last_time - Latest_Happend_Start_time
                          WHERE Name = ?''' 
                          ,[k])
            self.conn.commit()
```

and for specific

```
Latest_Happend_Start_time = Latest_Happend_Last_time - "datetime.timedelta(minutes='Plus_Val')",
```

Latest_Happend_Last_time is the current time value and Latest_Happend_Start_time is what time happened.

If "Latest_Happend_Last_time" is '2017-03-28 10:19:31.040088+08:00' and "Plus_Val" in the sql database is 0 ,

That code means '2017-03-28 10:19:31.040088+08:00' -"datetime.timedelta(minutes='0')"  = Latest_Happend_Start_time

but Latest_Happend_Start_time's actual result is "2017" not 2017-03-28 10:19:31.040088+08:00 the same value I expected.

and also if "Plus_Val" is 1 after "for" again, Latest_Happend_Start_time's actual result should be like 2017-03-28 10:18:31.040088+08:00.

```
How_Long_time =  Latest_Happend_Last_time - Latest_Happend_Start_time
```

I expected this will call int or float data type. but actual result is "0"

for example, 2017-03-28 10:19:31.040088+08:00 - 2017-03-28 10:18:31.040088+08:00 could be 1 (How_Long_time)

I want to get the result from 1 ~ . because How_Long_time means time difference check minutes or something between Latest_Happend_Last_time and Latest_Happend_Start_time.

and I already understand in Python. you can understand what I am trying with SQL in python after reading this code with datetime calculation

```
for i in range(check):
   Plus_Val=i
   Latest_Happend_Last_time  = datetime.datetime.now()
   Latest_Happend_Start_time= Latest_Happend_Last_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=Plus_Val)
   How_long_time = Latest_Happend_Last_time - Latest_Happend_Start_time
```

Please help to resolve this issues with SQL in python.

Thanks for reading

Comment: SQLite does not have a separate date datatype; your values are [stored as strings](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).